# Toolbar with show more button in Web Application (ASP.NET 2.0)

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, css, web

In an ASP.NET 2.0 application, there is a toolbar where few buttons (divs) are shown as displayed below:
[image]

When user resizes (compress) the browser window this looks like as shown below:
[image]

This is because the toolbar div’s height is auto so it wraps the divs to below. But, now I want to mention some fix height which shows only toolbar buttons in single row.

In expected behavior, if toolbar div buttons exceed the area then they should be shown like below as in desktop applications with a more button to access those buttons which are not displayed.
Like this:
[image]
[image]

Anyone, who can help me to achieve this or suggest some alternate solutions if expected behavior is not possible in web application. jQuery is also used in this application.
Help will be appreciated.

Comment: See http://jsfiddle.net/CTAKR/

Comment: Its really good. But, can we get something from jQuery built-in controls ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a simpler although probably not as flexible example as @PiLHA's
Also, it might need some tuning but it works! It checks how many items will fit in your 100% or whatever width container and acts accordingly.

[**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/DfZgQ/1/)

```
function topNavItems() {
    var items = $(".item");
    var listWidth = $(".list").width();
    var itemWidth = $(".item").width();
    var itemsFit = parseInt(Math.floor(listWidth / itemWidth));
    if (items.length > itemsFit) {
        $(".list").after("<div class='arrow'></div>");
        var array = [];
        $(".list .item").slice(itemsFit).each(function (index) {
            var value = $(this).text();
            array[index] = value;
        });
        $(".arrow").html("<select><option>>></option></select>");
        $.each(array, function (index, value) {
            $(".arrow select").append("<option>" + value + "</option>");
        });
    }    
}
topNavItems();
$(window).resize(function () {
    topNavItems();
});
```